# Regex modification for username validation

Tags: c, regex, linux

I'm using `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,14}` regex for validation username but I want to block username starting with digit or all digits,So what modification is required in this regex??

```
Content of temp.txt

user123
User123
USER
UsEr12345
123456
_12345

grep -w -E -o '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,14}' temp.txt
user123
User123
USER
UsEr12345
123456
_12345
```

But I want to block user name staring with _,digit and all digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you prohibit a username starting with a digit, you are also prohibiting usernames that consist only of a string of digits.  There's no need to deal with the second condition, since the first condition prevents that from happening.  So just lead with a character class that excludes digits (and underscore, etc)

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,13}$
```

In this pattern I also anchored to the end of the string, as your original regexp wasn't requiring the entire string to be matched.  By anchoring to the start and end of the string, you are enforcing that only those characters you allow may be present in any position.  The anchors at both ends also prevent strings longer than 14 characters being matched.

Comment: You'll need to reduce the quantifier from 5 to 4, to ensure it matches the correct minimum length.

Comment: At the top of his post he is demonstrating this regexp: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,14}`. I deducted one from the quantifiers in that regexp. Later in his post he demonstrates a different regexp: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,14}`.  No point guessing which he meant to use; Rahul can certainly figure out his quantifiers.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

EDIT:Now try this one

```
(?![0-9_])^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,14}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be appropriate:

```
^[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,13}$
```